# Reference to a javascript variable in an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to "link" a tag value to a javascript variable (and ideally to a function, but well a variable is a good start), by reference.
I know I can do a `myDom.value = myVar` but then if the value of `myVar` change the tag will not be modified.

Is it possible to do this (not using events, because it would be so heavy)?

Thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an MVVM framework like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Please provide some of your code so we can understand better

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can fake references by assigning objects to things, but only if the property you assign the object to is expecting an object and knows to pull data out of it instead of stringifying it and using it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure function around the variable. So instead of attaching the value, you attach a function which will return the variable:

```
myDom.valueAccessor = function(){ return value }
```

After this you can access the result as:

```
myDom.valueAccessor()
```

This will track the value in `value` as it changes. Obviously you could choose a snappier name for your function. This seems to work for me in Firefox.